# remove message notification through android code

Tags: android

Through my android app I want to clear/remove message notification (that is generated by default in android device) of an incoming message if it contains *keyword*. Can anyone please help how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use **NotificationListenerService api** and get notification id and text then clear notification by notification id.

```
@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = "";
        String ticker = "";
        String title = "";
        String text = "";
        String postTime = "";

        if (sbn.getPackageName() != null)
            pack = sbn.getPackageName();

        postTime = sbn.getPostTime() + "";
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

        CharSequence data = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);

        extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);

        if (data != null) {// notification title
            title = data.toString();
        }
        data = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (data != null) {// notification text
            text = data.toString();
        }
       String id= sbn.getKey()  ;// notification id    
    }
```

Comment: In my code I know when notification is generated so I don't need to implement listener for notification. Is there any way like `notification.getTitle().equal("keyword")`?

Comment: but how to get notification object programatically? I mean `notificationObject.getTilte()`

Comment: bro see my code or search on google about NotificationListenerService api.